# Is binding IsEnabled optional when binding Command?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, command

I noticed that the following code:

```
<Button Content="_Timbres..." 
    Command="{Binding Path=ShowTimbresCommand}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanExecuteShowTimbresCommand}"/>
```

behaves equally as:

```
<Button Content="_Timbres..." 
    Command="{Binding Path=ShowTimbresCommand}">
```

Meaning that the CanExecuteShowTimbresCommand is automatically bound to the IsEnabled property.
Is that true and why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually controls which accept a `Command` will set `IsEnabled` to `false` if the command's `CanExecute` is `false`, that's all there is to it.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx#commands_at_10000_feet):

> Another purpose of commands is to indicate whether an action is available. [...] A button can subscribe to the [CanExecuteChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged.aspx) event and be disabled if [CanExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx) returns **false** or be enabled if [CanExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx) returns **true**.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: If you so far always dealed with `IsEnabled` yourself that is indeed the case.

Comment: Yes I have currently everywhere a command binding together with IsEnabled = CanExecute for that same command. I assume the extra edit you made in the answer is done automatically.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: Yes, when you set the command property that should happen internally (i haven't seen a .NET control which does not follow this).