# Button IsEnabled binding not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

`Button.IsEnabled` doesn't work properly.

I have debugged the code and the setter for the property was hit with the "true" value. But the button is still disabled.

View.xaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,20,0,0" >
        <Button Name="ButtonOk" Content="OK" Margin="0,0,4,0" IsEnabled="{Binding SomethingIsValid}"  Command="{Binding CommandOk}" />
        <Button Name="ButtonCancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="0,0,4,0" IsCancel="True" /
</StackPanel>
```

View.xaml.cs:

```
...
public View(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.viewModel = viewModel;
    this.DataContext = viewModel;            
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public bool SomethingIsValid
{
   get
   {
      return somethingIsValid;
   }
   set
   {
      this.somethingIsValid= value;
      this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SomethingIsValid);
   }
}

#region IDataErrorInfo
public string this[string columnName]
{
   get
   {
      this.SomethingIsValid= false;

      if ("SomeName" == columnName)
      {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Status))
         {
            return "Please bla bla..";
         }
      }

      this.SomethingIsValid = true;
      return string.Empty;
   }
}

public string Error
{
   get
   {
      return string.Empty;
   }
}
#endregion

public ICommand CommandOk
{
   get
   {
      if (this.commandOk == null)
      {
         this.commandOk = new RelayCommand(this.CommandOkAktion, () => this.SomethingIsValid );
      }

      return this.commandOk;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your command: `CommandOk`, normally the button's Enable and Disable is controlled by a `CanCommandExecute` defined in the binding Command.

Comment: As @Bolu suggests, it could be your command that is disabling the button (the **ICommand** interface has a **CanExecute** method: if this returns `false` then the button bound to the command will be disabled).

Comment: @Bolu Command Ok call Model and store the information in DB

Comment: @Bolu - sorry wrong information - I will post the code now

Comment: @Bolu - I have updated my question with Command

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using a command, it's not a good idea to separately bind the IsEnabled property of the button. 
Instead you should provide the correct value in the "CanExecute" of the command. This will enable the button as well.

Comment: Thank you for you response! I have upvoted :) I have debugged and CanExecute(true) was shown

Comment: if you set a break point into the CanExecute method. Is it really executed? It's only evaluated in case the button is in the logical focus area.

Comment: I dont know what exactly you mean. This method  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute();
            } is called

Comment: Have some links or something like this about you information thas its not good to bind IsEnabled if command is already used for the button?

Comment: @MikroDel, in your case you are just binding to one property, which dose not matter so much (still duplicates). `CanExecute` is a function and can take parameter, so it will be much more useful in other cases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346328/is-binding-isenabled-optional-when-binding-command

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I had the Command binding and I completely forgot. I realized what was happening.

Comment: Why would this be a better idea? There are scenarios where some other event would need to disable this button. For this we would either ways have a boolean. Wouldn't binding this boolean just be cleaner?

Answer (score 31):

If anyone is still having trouble with this - make sure that your IsEnabled property comes after the Command property.

```
<Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding StartEnabled}" />
```

- works

```
  <Button IsEnabled="{Binding StopEnabled}" Command="{Binding StopCommand}"  />
```

- does not work

Note that both of my commands can always execute. An easier fix for me.

Comment: This was the simplest answer for me and should be listed somewhere as a "gotcha" of using both the Command property and the IsEnabled property together.

Comment: this worked for me too, but really seems like a bug that should be fixed :-)

Comment: There is a Xamarin Issue on this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2758

Comment: This is the right answer! The one and only.

Comment: 2021 I don't think this works anymore

Comment: usual xamarin... I can't believe I wasted half-hour on this... my problem was that I was binding it to a checkbox and was starting as enabled... while the checkbox was not checked... then tapping on checkbox twice and was disabling it...

Comment: 2022, still this works and the bug not yet fixed

Comment: Can't believe it... This answer probably spared me hours of attempts. Isn't there an issue in the official repo?

Comment: I hate it. I've also been burned by setting maxValue to something lower than the current minValue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using RelayCommand, you can use the second parameter as boolean method which indicates whether command can be executed:

```
public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute);
```

Usage:

```
this.DetermineCommand = new RelayCommand(this.Determine, () => this.IsValid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Form what I can see in your posted code, if nothing calls `this["SomeName"]`, your `SomethingIsValid` will always be `false`, and that is why your button is showing `disabled`. So my suggestion/solution is:

Remove `IsEnabled` binding from xaml (as you won't need this if your Command binding is working correctly):

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,20,0,0" >
    <Button Name="ButtonOk" Content="OK" Margin="0,0,4,0" Command="{Binding CommandOk}" />
    <Button Name="ButtonCancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="0,0,4,0" IsCancel="True" /
 </StackPanel>
```

Change your ViewModel code to something like below (your current Command definition is OK, so no change to that part). The code below makes sure when executing `CanCommandExecute`, it will re-examine `SomethingIsValid`:

```
public bool SomethingIsValid
{
   get
   {
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Error);
   }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
   get
   {
      switch(columnName)
      {
          case "SomeName":
          {
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Status))
               {
                  return "Please bla bla..";
               }
               break;
          }
          case "SomeOtherName":
          {
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.OtherProperty))
               {
                  return "Please bla bla..";
               }
               break;
          }

      }
      return string.Empty;         

   }
}

public string Error
{
   get
   {
      return this["SomeName"]+this["SomeOtherName"];
   }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: This way OK button will not be shown gray for the user (disabled). I want to avoid it will be clicked.

Comment: @MikroDel, it shouldn't, as when `this.Status` is null or empty, `SomethingIsValid` will return `false` ? please do some debugging.

Comment: @MikroDel, check [Basic MVVM and ICommand usuage example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-usuage-example), (just in case, and make sure you are not missing something obvious).

Comment: This is like an advice - use google or read msdn. I have posted my code to be helped in the situation I have missed something obvious.

Comment: I  havent found the information that using IsEnabled and Commnad together is a bad pratice.

Comment: @MikroDel, the link is just for you to make sure you have basic knowledge to understand what I have posted in my answer. as that should achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @MikroDel, Check my first paragraph for the reason why your code is not working.

Comment: What can I do in the situation where I have "SomeName" and "SomeOtherName". How should I implement my `public string Error` in this case?

Comment: @MikroDel, updated my answer, you can just add it in your `IDataErrorInfo` region

Comment: My OK button is never disabled with this code. So I have no IsEnabled anymore - only command and the OK button is always enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your ViewModel, so the view gets notfied when the property gets updated.

Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think OP already done that: `this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SomethingIsValid);`

Comment: Thank you for you response! Bolu is right - I have implemented it already and call it too.

Comment: Yes, I'm indeed new on here... First lesson: Read code samples more carefully before answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your commands like this:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
async Task Refresh()
{
    await LoadListAsync();
}
```

Then you can pass your `boolean` as parameter into the **Relay** attribute as follows:

```cs
[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanRefresh))]
async Task Refresh()
{
    await LoadListAsync();
}
```

Refer to [MAUI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand#enabling-and-disabling-commands) for further detail.

Answer (score -3):

I solved the issue by binding the value of IsEnabled. Explicitly setting it to False did not work.

**This worked:**

```
<Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonsEnabled}" />
```

**This did not work:**

```
<Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" IsEnabled="False" />
```